# db2 use query result in variable

Tags: variables, db2

i want to use the result of a query as an input in another query.
What might make it difficult: The variable is the schema in the database.

```
CREATE or replace VARIABLE myschema varchar(15) ;
set myschema = (select owner from syscat.tables where tabname = 'xyz'); 
select count(name) as result from myschema.USR02 where USTYP = 'A'; 
DROP VARIABLE myschema;
```

This is my last try, after i failed using declare.
But i get an error, because "myschema" is used as a string, and of course there is no schema with name "myschema". The result of the first query is not used.

If I just run the first two lines, i get the schemaname as result. Do i have to mark the variable in a special way? The goal is just the result of the query in line 3 by using the dynamic value of "myschema".

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you have to use dynamic SQL (forming a custom SQL query through string manipulation) if you want to deal with table, schema, or column names dynamically:

This is the basic idea:

```
execute immediate 'select * from ' || myschema || '.USR02';
```

However, you can't just run a bare select in dynamic SQL; you have to put the result in something.  And the whole thing must be in a compound SQL block.  So the full example would look something like this (simplified query for space).

This query assumes that a table called "result" exists to store the result you are returning.

```
begin
    declare myschema varchar(100) default '';
    set myschema = (select owner from syscat.tables where tabname = 'xyz');

    execute immediate 'insert into result select count(*) from ' || myschema || '.USR02';
end

select * from result;
```

Note that within the block, you can simply declare a variable (as shown in my example).  So you don't have to declare a global variable for this purpose, unless you want it to persist beyond this one statement.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have write access to the databases. The code is integrated in a script and the provided user is read-only. I would run the queries sequentially and store the result in a variable, but this is not possible. So my goal has to be: Get both information in one query with the provided user.

Comment: @rysk, you should be able to use a session table for this method (`declare global temporary table...`) even if you have a read only user.